# How use struct with union in c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

Hi I writing a wrapper in c# and i have some problem. I have this struct in c++.

```
typedef struct pjmedia_format
{
    pj_uint32_t id;
    pjmedia_type type;
    pjmedia_format_detail_type detail_type;
    union
    {
    pjmedia_audio_format_detail aud;
    pjmedia_video_format_detail vid;
    char user[PJMEDIA_FORMAT_DETAIL_USER_SIZE];
    } det;
} pjmedia_format;
```

This is link to this struct [pjmedia_format](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest-2/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__format.htm)

in c# I have this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct pjmedia_format
{
    public uint id;
    public pjmedia_type type;
    public pjmedia_format_detail_type detail_type;
    public det_t det;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct det_t
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public pjmedia_audio_format_detail aud;
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public pjmedia_video_format_detail vid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    [FieldOffset(60)]
    public char[] user;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct pjmedia_audio_format_detail
{
    public uint clock_rate;
    public uint channel_count;
    public uint frame_time_usec;
    public uint bits_per_sample;
    public int avg_bps;
    public int max_bps;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct pjmedia_video_format_detail
{
    public pjmedia_rect_size size;
    public pjmedia_ratio fps;
    public int avg_bps;
    public int max_bps;
}
```

and when i want to use this struct i get this error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException was unhandled.
>   Message="A method signature is not PInvoke compatible with the element."

I try to use some attributes like size or pack but it doesn't help (probably i use it wrong). I tested singly other struct e.g. pjmedia_video_format_detail and they works well. Any advice?

Best regards
Andrzej

Comment: why don't you make `Interface` ?

Comment: @Shivan how would that help *in any way* with a PInvoke structure with specific layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a union, shouldn't that be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct det_t
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public pjmedia_audio_format_detail aud;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public pjmedia_video_format_detail vid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public char[] user;
}
```

i.e. overlapping? <s>Also, you might need `user` to be a *fixed buffer* rather than an array.</s>

Comment: In fact the `ByValArray` is fine

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ code, `det` is a [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29). That means that *all* the fields have zero offset, they are overlayed. Simply change your C# declaration to match by using `[FieldOffset(0)]` for all fields in `det_t`.

Comment: if i change to `[FieldOffset(0)]` i get another error >System.ExecutionEngineException

Comment: Hard for us to debug that for you. We don't know what's on the other side of the interface and we can't see your calling code.

Comment: this exception is calling if I try to use this [function](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest-2/pjmedia/docs/html/group__video__device__reference.htm#gafe6d82fb429b088fac5811d01921928a) in c# i have this
`[DllImport(PJSIP_DLL)]
        private static extern int pjmedia_vid_dev_get_info(int id, out pjmedia_vid_dev_info info);`

Comment: What about calling convention? I'd guess the C++ code uses `cdecl`. You'd need to add `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to your `DllImport` attribute.

Comment: I added it but i doesn't help :/
if I have
 
`[FieldOffset(0)]...`
`[FieldOffset(36)]...`
`[FieldOffset(60)]...`
this function works, i have some data in _pjmedia_vid_dev_info_ but in
_pjmedia_vid_dev_info.fmt[]_ i have only null values

Comment: in c++ pjsip uses `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: im sorry for my last reply if i set some `[FieldOffset(..)]` in _pjmedia_vid_dev_info_ i have some value also in _fmt_, but when i try to use pjmedia_format in [pjmedia_vid_codec_param](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest-2/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__vid__codec__param.htm) there is an error.

Comment: Use `FieldOffset(0)` for all members of a union. What is the calling convention of the C++ code? I have asked you that twice now.

Comment: calling conversion of c++ code is like you write earlier `cdecl`, and if I change to `FieldOffset(0)` and add `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to `DllImport` attribute i get `System.TypeLoadException was unhandled Message = "Could not load type 'pjsipdll.det_t' from assembly 'pjsipdll, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' because it contains a field object to postpone '0 'desktop applications is incorrectly aligned or partially cover the field of non-object field." `

Comment: We can't do this in comments. Both my answer and Marc's completely address everything that is in your question. There's nothing more to add to this question. If you have follow ups that should be a new question. Make sure you include more detail in future questions.