# Make optional types return value by ref

Tags: c#, nullable

I have the following class which holds a list of structs. It is important these are value types for performance reasons.

```
class Container<T> where T : struct, IComponent
{
    private Component<T>[] components;
    ref Component GetComponent(int index)
    {
        return ref components[index];
    }
    ...
}
```

The component class looks somthing like this

```
struct Component<T> : where T : struct, IComponent
{
    public ID EntityID { get; }
    public T data;
}
```

This allows me to acess my data like

```
ref var component = container.Get(1);

// for example
component.data.x = 2;
```

However, i'd like to make the data optional - something like:

> ```
> struct Component<T> : where T : struct, IComponent
> {
>     public ID EntityID { get; }
>     public T? data;
> }
> ```

However, this would not allow the component data to be altered at all

```
component.data.Value.x = 1;
```

Gives the error

> Property 'data' access returns temporary value. Cannot modify struct
> member when accessed struct is not classified as a variable

I understand this is because the nullable value returns a copy of the value, my question is is there a way to return this value by ref instead? Is there some other workaround?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "make the data optional".  Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: By optional I mean [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006965/how-use-struct-with-union-in-c-sharp ("C# union" as the search term) is what you are looking for, but that's *not exactly code you expect to read* and you really should reconsider.

Comment: You should probably restate the question, then, since optional and nullable are two completely different things.

Comment: What is `IComponent` in this context?

Comment: Since `Nullable<T>` doesn't define a `ref T GetValue();`, no you can't get a reference to `component.data.Value.x`. You can only assign the entire `.Value`. But you could instead have your own "null" flag (and deal with any threading issues).

Comment: Which is because `Nullable<T>.Value` is a property. Not a field.